# Good books regarding SharePoint 2013 exam 70-331

Tags: 2013, certification, books

I was wondering what books you can recommend in order to obtain the Microsoft SharePoint 70-331 exam or for learning more about SharePoint 2013 in regards to administration.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the exam, i think the official book from Microsoft might be a good choice to begin with.

[Exam Ref MCSE 70-331: Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-mcse-70-331-core-solutions-of-microsoft-sharepoint-9780735678088)

For basic 2013 administration, i can recommend this book. It's easy to read, they cover up all the basics and the authors got a great sense of humor.

[Professional SharePoint 2013 Administration](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=407)